# How to create a tabbed interface in Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom, frontend, dom-events

I'm trying to create a tabbed interface in Javascript which will allow a user to click on a button atop each interface in order to make the div under it become active while the other 'tabs'/divs recede to the background. I'm not quite sure I got that out right so attached is a screenshot of what I'm trying to make:

[image: screenshot]

My code attaches one button -- beside the first div-- instead of all three and returns an error that says `nodeChildren[j].getAttribute("data-tabname") is not a function` although as far as I know, it seems it is.

I'll post my JavaScript code then add a link to fiddle where everything is.

```
function asTabs(node) {
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var tempArray = [];
var nodeChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes);

nodeChildren.filter(function(){
for (var i = 0; i < nodeChildren.length; i++) {
if (nodeChildren[i].nodeType === 1) {
tempArray += nodeChildren[i];
return tempArray;
}
}
});
nodeChildren.forEach(function (){
for (var j = 0; j < nodeChildren.length; j++) {
node.insertBefore(button, nodeChildren[j]);
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var k = 0; k < buttons.length; k++) {
buttons[k].innerHTML = nodeChildren[j].getAttribute("data-tabname").textContent;
}
}
});

var hide = nodeChildren.slice(1);
for (var l = 0; l < hide.length; l++) {
hide[l].className = "hide";
}
buttons[k].addEventListener("click", function (){
if (nodeChildren[j].className = "") {
nodeChildren[j].className = "hide";
}
else nodeChildren[j].className = "";
});
  }
  asTabs(document.querySelector("#wrapper"));
```

Then here's my fiddle containing comments explaining what is being tried to achieve on each line
https://jsfiddle.net/nmeri17/nmswdota/

Comment: You can do this fast with the tab found in jquery.ui  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @Bindrid perhaps yes. But I'm trying to do it with JavaScript specifically

Comment: Improved my code up till this point. Doesn't return errors and does not work either. If anyone is up to it, I'll really appreciate [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vomiha/edit?js,console,output)